# What can I do if I want to compare elements in an array while walking it

Tags: python, arrays

I wanna compare elements when walking array.

Here is what the compiler said:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I know how `.any()` and `all()` are used to check if the element is in the array, and they return `true` or `false`. But I don't know how to revise this code:

```py
a = np.arange(11, 36)
a = a.reshape(5, 5)
for ele in a:
  if ele >= 20:
     print(ele)
```

Comment: `print(ele)` before `if` and you will see problem. You try to do `if [11 12 13 14 15] >= 20:`

Answer (score 3):

You are reshaping your numpy array.

```
a = np.arange(11, 36)

print(a)
[11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 35]
a = a.reshape(5, 5)
print(a)
[[11 12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25]
 [26 27 28 29 30]
 [31 32 33 34 35]]
```

arange gives a 1-dimensional array. Calling reshape(5,5) gives you a 2-dimensional numpy array, so looping over 'a' will give you an array each time. You can do this by looping twice

```
for row in a:
    for ele in row:
        if ele >= 20:
            print(ele)
```

You can note that if you do not call reshape, then your original loop will work just fine.